# Magento checkout stuck with Submitting Order Information (using custom theme )

Tags: magento, themes, payment

Magento checkout stuck with “Submitting Order Information”

Magento Version Magento ver. 1.9.0.1

The entire process works in the checkout (Billing info, shipping info, shipping method, etc.) except when one finally decides to submit the order, (hit "place order” button) it just hangs at "submitting order information”. After sitting there for a few minutes, the shopper will be returned to the shopping cart, and the order never makes it through!

I hope and assume others have had the same problem? How to fix it? I’m worried that it might be the theme because I’ve haven’t had much luck finding the solution on the internet. (2checkout extension i m using for payment )

Comment: Check in console any error when placing order.

Comment: Check you do not have any 'echo', 'print'. check for error logs.

Comment: Guys i am really very new and i feel really helpless when it comes to this kind of stuff, please guide me how do it> please

Comment: @MaxWebber, look for var/log/, var/report folders for any errors

Comment: @DushyantJoshi it give error a:5:{i:0;s:46:"The requested Payment Method is not available.";i:1;s:3351:"#0 /home/name/public_html/domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Info.php(82): Mage::throwException('The requested P...')

Comment: disable or enable that method

Comment: @DushyantJoshi sorry , but how to do that ?

Comment: It may be related to country specific. checke here. http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/808/2206

Comment: @DushyantJoshi it works on magento basic theme which comes after the installation i tried it on my local server but after i install any custom theme it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Just downgrade your extension version to 2.3.3